# Best way to let multiple UIButtons share the same appearance

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

What is the best practice to let multiple buttons share the same appearance?

Right now I'm creating those buttons in a loop like this:

```
for i in 0..<10{
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle(String(i), for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3137254902, green: 0.2745098039, blue: 0.2745098039, alpha: 0.5977632705)
    numberButtons.append(button)
    button.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.04296875, green: 0.04296875, blue: 0.04296875, alpha: 0.5).cgColor
    button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    button.addTarget(self, action:  #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
}
```

What is Swift way to do such things? Subclass UIButton? Or add some initialising method as extension?

Comment: Have you looked into the capabilities of UIAppearance https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiappearance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Create a subclass of `UIButton`.

2- Put all your customizations in its constructor.

3- Use it for your buttons (in your storyboard or in code).

The discussion in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38161500/4763963) will help you subclass `UIButton` and customize it in the way you want.

And this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31180090/4763963) provides a general rule of thumb on when to use extensions and when to use inheritance.